# How do I get the rendered HTML of a component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'd like to get the innerHTML of a rendered component in Vue 3 but I don't figure out how.
I know how to do this with `refs` on standard HTML markup, but it doesn't work with components.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div ref="hello"><span>Hello World</span></div>
    <HelloWorld ref="helloworld"><span>Hello World</span></HelloWorld>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref, unref } from 'vue';
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';

const hello = ref();
const helloworld = ref();

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(unref(hello).innerHTML); // <span>Hello World</span>
  console.log(unref(helloworld).innerHTML); // undefined
});
</script>
```

I'm not using SSR, my current requirement is on a SPA.

I managed to do it by wrapping `<HelloWorld>` into a div with and id and querying it but that's a bit crappy.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean [Template Refs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html#template-refs)? The documentation uses `.value` if that makes sense. I would check with [Vue DevTools](https://devtools.vuejs.org/)

Comment: @PeterKrebs, `unref` is a more priority way. allows you to avoid problems, for example, with getting into the argument not `Ref` one. In this example, changing `unref` to `.value` will not change anything.

Comment: Chances are there's a better way to do what you're attempting. You might ask about your larger goal rather than this technique. See the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 0):

I don’t remember the exact sources, but I came across code like this:

```js
const stopWatch = watch(helloworld, value => {
  if (value) {
    stopWatch();
    // TODO: Start using the element
  }
}, { immediate: true });
```

The problem is that when the current component is finished mounting, the child component may not yet have time to be mounted.

As part of a more reasonable description, you can wrap it all in a function:

```js
function onRefReady (ref, cb) {
  const stopWatch = watch(ref, value => {
    if (value) {
      stopWatch();
      cb(value);
    }
  }, { immediate: true });
  onScopeDispose(stopWatch);
}
```

And use it like this:

```js
onRefReady(helloworld, el => {
  // TODO: Start using the element
})
```

In short, according to the written code:

- `watch(ref, fn)` — calls `fn` every time the value of `ref` changes. Returns the function (`stopWatch`) that `watch` call will terminate.
- `{ immediate: true }` — says to run the passed function immediately, in case `ref` already has a non-empty value.
- `onScopeDispose(stopWatch)` — says to stop watching changes if the component is destroyed.

This code uses `stopWatch` to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `ref="helloWorldRef"` to the component then `helloWorldRef.value?.$el` it the same as `document.querySelector(".hello-world")`. You can get `.children`, `.clientWidth`, ... the same as the `querySelector`.

Note that the optional chaining is necessary because it can be `null` if not mounted yet. You'd have to implement something to be sure it is available and assigned.

E.g.

```js
watch(
  () => helloWorldRef.value?.$el,
  (n) => console.log(n)
);
```